# Problem with a simple c program regarding lcm

Tags: c

Need to find lcm of two numbers using functions .i wrote the   function it keeps returning answer as 45. any help would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int lcm(num1,num2);
int main()
{
    int num1, num2, rem;
    printf("Enter two numbers!\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
    int lcm(num1,num2);
    printf("Lcm is : %d ",rem);

}
int lcm(int p,int q)
{
int rem;
   if(p>q)
   {
       if(p%q==0)
       rem=p;
       else{ rem=p*q;}
   }
   else if (q>p)
   {
       if(q%p==0)
        rem=q;
       else
        rem=p*q;
   }
return rem;
}
```

Comment: `lcm` is not `p*q` .It is  `p*q/gcd(p,q)`.

Comment: In addition to @hanie. Format your code and show us what numbers you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first your method of finding `lcm` is wrong. `lcm` is not `p*q` .It is `(p*q)/gcd(p,q)`.

second your function `lcm` prototype `int lcm(num1,num2);` is wrong  .You should add arguments data type to it `int lcm(int num1,int num2);`.

then `int rem` in `main` is uninitialized ,if you want it to be `lcm` you should do it like this: `rem =lcm(num1,num2);`

look:

```
int gcd(int a, int b);
int lcm(int num1,int num2);

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, rem;
    printf("Enter two numbers!\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
     rem = lcm(num1, num2);
    printf("Lcm is : %d ", rem);

}
int lcm(int p, int q)
{
    int rem;
    if (p > q)
    {
        if (p % q == 0)
            rem = p;
        else { rem = (p * q)/gcd(q,p); }
    }
    else if (q > p)
    {
        if (q % p == 0)
            rem = q;
        else
            rem = (p * q) / gcd(q, p);
    }
    return rem;
}
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    return gcd(b % a, a);
}
```

there are other method to find `lcm` like this:

```
int main()
{
    int i, num1, num2, max, lcm=1;

    printf("Enter any two numbers to find LCM: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);

    max = (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;

    i = max;

    while(1)
    {
        if(i%num1==0 && i%num2==0)
        {

            lcm = i;

            break;
        }

        i += max;
    }

    printf("LCM of %d and %d = %d", num1, num2, lcm);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3386109 you are right ,but this is for time saving. In a case that one number is divisible by other one there is no need to call `gcd`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Making a lot of mistakes while learning functions .Btw can you tell me how does this statement work?-
max = (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;

Comment: @beserker5781 sorry I didn't see your question that time. it checks `if(num1>num2)`  then `max=num1` and  `if(num1<num2)` then `max=num2`. It's a if_ else statement. `(condition) ?  return if it was true : return if it was wrong`